# Sending and receiving data using Jquery 

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am at basic level of application development.

I wanted to know how I can send and get this data with JQuery any new version.

I also want it to support all browsers.

I'm just using simple Ajax but I know it is possible with Jquery and im not able to figure it out.

```
function SendData() {
    var data = "action=check&uid=" + uid + "&fbuid=" + fb_uid + ";
    var url = "http://www.example.com/call.php";
    var ajax = new AJAXInteraction(url, CheckRate);
    ajax.doPost(data);
};

function CheckRate(Content) {
    response = JSON.parse(Content);
    Rate = response.stat.rate;
    document['getElementById']('ERate')['value'] = Rate;
};

function AJAXInteraction(url, callback) {
    var req = init();
    req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    function init() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    function processRequest() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                if (callback) callback(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    this.doGet = function () {
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
    this.doPost = function (str) {
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        req.send(str);
    }
};
```

I am able to solve first part And still dont know rest:

```
function SendData(){
    dataString = "action=check&uid=" + uid + "&fbuid=" + fb_uid + ";
    url = "http://www.example.com/call.php";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
    });
};
```

My problem is how i will read response

```
function CheckRate(Content) {
    response = JSON.parse(Content);
    Rate = response.stat.rate;
    document['getElementById']('ERate')['value'] = Rate;
};
```

Comment: Please make your question title more descriptive.

Comment: Check this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and try to read the official documentation first. In the most cases thee will be examples with documentation.

Comment: Please attempt this yourself at least. The jQuery documentation and API is very useful and easy to use. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
function SendData() {
    dataString = "action=check&uid=" + uid + "&fbuid=" + fb_uid + ";
    url = "http://www.example.com/call.php";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString, // sending data
        success: function (data) {
            CheckRate(data); // receiving data
        }
    });
};

// function body should looks like this
function CheckRate(Content) {
    response = JSON.parse(Content);
    Rate = response.stat.rate;
    document['getElementById']('ERate')['value'] = Rate;
};
```